# Python import mechanism and module mocks

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, python-importlib

This is more an effort to understand how Python (3.9 in this instance) works than an effort to solve an actual problem so please bear with me and disregard the nonsensical way of m3. I just wanted to replicate something I'm dealing with.

I have the following structure:

```
├── m1.py
└── m2
    └── m3
        ├── __init__.py
        └── m3.py
```

m2/m3/**init**.py:

```py
from .m3 import *
```

m2/m3/m3.py:

```py
def m3func():
    print('m3 func is here')
```

From now on I will be making changes to m1.py

This is working and I was expecting it to work:

```py
import m2.m3
m2.m3.m3func()
```

This is not failing so it replaced the module for the Mock. I was also expecting this to work the way it does.

```py
import sys
from unittest.mock import Mock
sys.modules['m2.m3'] = Mock()
import m2.m3 as alias
alias.m3func()
```

Same for this

```py
import sys
from unittest.mock import Mock
sys.modules['m2.m3'] = Mock()
from m2 import m3
m3.m3func()
```

I don't understand what's happening here:

```py
import sys
from unittest.mock import Mock
sys.modules['m2.m3'] = Mock()
import m2.m3
m2.m3.m3func()
```

```
m2.m3.m3func()
AttributeError: module 'm2' has no attribute 'm3'
```

What are the differences between `import m2.m3`, `from m2 import m3` and `import m2.m3 as alias`
What else am I not understanding and is there a way to fix the last version so that it won't throw the AttributeError? Im my example m2 is empty but in actuality, I don't want to swap it out entirely because it does contain things that I care about. I would just like to target m3. Is there a recommendation as far as best practices go to using code like this: `m2.m3.m3func()`?

Comment: Is there an `__init__.py` in `m2`?

Comment: No, but I could add one if required.

Comment: See what happens if you do

Comment: I get the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely [read the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html), if you haven't yet.

Whenever you use an import statement, the following happens:

1. Python searches the module, and processes newly discovered modules found along the way
2. Python introduces one or multiple variables to use whatever was imported

### Discovery Problems

Python uses `sys.modules` internally for searching modules, and updates its entries as it finds modules and parent modules along the way. So, when you import `m2.m3.m3`, it adds entries with keys 'm2', 'm2.m3', 'm2.m3.m3' to store objects referencing those modules. You can use the following function to debug `sys.modules` before/after every statement.

```
def print_status_relevant_modules():
    import sys
    print(sys.modules.get("m2", "<m2 not loaded>"))
    print(sys.modules.get("m2.m3", "<m2.m3 not loaded>"))
    print(sys.modules.get("m2.m3.m3", "<m2.m3.m3 not loaded>"))
    print()
```

Whenever Python discovers a new package (a directory with a `__init__.py` file in it) or a `module.py` module, it will also process that module. In this case, when Python discovers the existence of the module `m2.m3`, it will execute the contents of `m2/m3/__init__.py`, and thus execute the import statement `from .m3 import *`, resulting in the discovery of the module `m2.m3.m3` (and the introduction of the local variable `m3func` to `m2.m3`).

Your problems start when start mocking the entry with key "m2.m3" in sys.modules, because now you have disrupted Python's process of searching for modules. Because you mocked the entry for the module `m2.m3` in sys.modules beforehand, Python thinks that it has already processed this module, so Python will never execute its `__init__.py` file. As a result, `m2.m3.m3` will never be discovered, no entry will be added, and the local variable for `m3func` will never be introduced to `m2.m3`.

If you wonder why you are not seeing any errors when mocking the module's entry, even though you are calling the `m3func()`, it's because mocks will accept any calls, expecting you to later verify that a certain call was made.

### Different Import Statements

The big difference between all the different import statements is which local variables are introduced:

- `import m2.m3` results in a local variable `m2` with attribute `m3`; the variable that is introduced refers to a Module instance representing the module `m2`
- `from m2 import m3` results in a local variable `m3`; the variable that is introduced refers to a Module instance representing the module `m2.m3`
- `import m2.m3 as alias` results in a local variable `alias`; the variable that is introduced refers to a Module instance representing the module `m2.m3`

You can use the statement `print(dir())` anywhere to see which local variables are defined, or on objects.

```
print(dir())    # m2 is not defined
import m2.m3
print(dir())    # m2 is defined
print(dir(m2))  # shows that m2 has an attribute m3
```

As an added bonus, the statement `from .m3 import *` in `m2/m3/__init__.py` results in all local variables of `m2.m3.m3` to be imported to `m2.m3`. In this case, only the variable `m3func` is added.

**When you use the import statement `import m2.m3`, the local variable `m2` is introduced, which refers to a `Module` instance representing the module m2. While searching for modules, Python should've discovered the module m2.m3, and added the attribute `m3` to the `Module` instance representing the module m2, to refer to the `Module` instance representing the module m2.m3. However, because you mocked `sys.modules['m2.m3']` beforehand, the module m2.m3 is never discovered, and thus the attribute `m3` is never added to the `Module` instance representing module m2. This eventually results in an error, when you try to access `m2.m3`.**

**When you use the import statement `import m2.m3 as alias`, the local variable `alias` that is introduced refers to a `Module` instance representing the module m3. However, because you mocked `sys.modules['m2.m3']` beforehand, Python thinks that it has already discovered the module m2.m3, and returns the value of `sys.modules['m2.m3']`. So, the variable `alias` ends up referring to the `Mock` instance instead of a `Module` instance representing module m2.m3, and you get no errors, because the `Mock` instance accepts all calls.**

**The same thing happens when you use the import statement `from m2 import m3`; the variable `m3` will end up referring to the `Mock` instance.**

### How To Fix Your Problem

As far as I know, you messed with Python's import system to a point where you cannot rely on it anymore to "just use" `m2.m3` or `m2.m3.m3`. Python will find a way to complain in one way or another.

This is probably a situation where the actual problem is a design problem, and mocking is never going to be the right answer, and just cause more problems in the long run, however, I don't know what the actual situation is. However, you should try to find a way that avoids this whole situation.